# How to secure prisma endpoint deployed to heroku

Tags: heroku, graphql, prisma

I deployed prisma PostgreSQL and yoga server to heroku,

but the graphql endpoint is public, and anyone can mutate from it.

is there a straightforward way of doing it like hasura does:
https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/deployment/securing-graphql-endpoint.html

PS: I didn't use docker to deploy it, i deployed everything through the prisma wizard in: [prisma console](https://app.prisma.io)

Answer (score 0):

You need a Prisma "secret" to protect your endpoint so that only you and your applications can access/mutate the data. Prisma calls this a `managementApiSecret` (see [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-server/authentication-and-security-kke4/)).

I'm not very familiar with the Prisma console, but if you deploy your Prisma server to Heroku with something like a `prisma.yml` file then you can specify a `secret:` line like this: `secret: ${env: PRISMA_SECRET}`. You can then set a Config Var in the settings for your Prisma server on Heroku where the key is `PRISMA_SECRET` and the value is a random string. I believe you want to do the same thing when using the `prisma deploy` command. So you're `prisma.yml` should look something like this:

```
endpoint: ${env:PRISMA_ENDPOINT_PROD}
datamodel: datamodel.graphql
secret: ${env:PRISMA_SECRET}
hooks:
  post-deploy:
      - graphql get-schema -p prisma
```

Then you'll need to specify that same secret in your Yoga server so that it can access the Prisma server. It's hard to help you with this without seeing your code for the Yoga server, but mine uses the `prisma-binding` package like this:

```
const { Prisma } = require('prisma-binding');

const db = new Prisma({
    typeDefs: 'src/generated/prisma.graphql',
    endpoint: process.env.PRISMA_ENDPOINT_PROD,
    secret: process.env.PRISMA_SECRET,
    debug: false, // Turn on to console.log queries and mutations
});

module.exports = db;
```

You can see that the Yoga server connects to the Prisma database with the secret specified. The Yoga server is deployed on Heroku and I've specified the `PRISMA_SECRET` environment variable in the Heroku settings for the Yoga server.

This setup though will prevent you from going to your Prisma endpoint in your browser and manually querying and mutating the data in your database through the GraphQL playground. There may be a way around this but I'm not sure how. Also note that this won't give you the nice login interface that Hasura appears to give you.

If you want more code to follow you can view this GitHub [repo](https://github.com/wesbos/Advanced-React) by Wes Bos, which is what he uses for his course called "Fullstack Advanced React & GraphQL".

Comment: Thank you spencer for replying,
My website is build on top of what Wes Bos did, almost the same setup, still i was facing the same problem.
This is how i solved the problem, probably not as secure as using managementApiSecret. but it did what i was looking for.
The start function from GraphQLServer has an option called "playground", which you can set to false to not show the playground.